# Fetching data from a remote script

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I need to fetch the data dynamically (as the user types) from my database. I had tried looking at the `typeahead`
examples, but I do not understand how could I implement the remote implementation.

```
<div id="remote">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Oscar winners for Best Picture">
</div>

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
```

This requires the array `states` to be present locally. But I need to get the data from my server side script. How could I do this?

Comment: you should try the example - https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote

Comment: @Dekay What is `source: bestPictures` here?

Comment: this is the name of the variable above which creates a `Bloodhound` object... this `Bloodhound` object describes how your data will be accessed

Comment: you also need to include the typeahead budle as js resources `typeahead.bundle.js (bloodhound.js + typeahead.jquery.js)` it requires jQuery 1.9+

Comment: @aashna did you find your answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

To use a remote datasource, it is recommended that you also use the bloodhound engine.

You will want to define your bloodhound instance, setting a remote option:

```
var taSource = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  identify: function(obj) {
    return obj.Value;
  },
  remote: todos
});
```

In this instance I've created an `options` hash, that holds the configuration of my remote source:

```
var urlRoot = '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var todos = {
  url: urlRoot + '/todos',
  prepare: function(query, settings) {
    settings.url += '?q=' + query;
    return settings;
  },
  filter: function(data) {
    return $.map(data, function(object) {
        return {
          Id: object.id,
          Value: object.title
        };
    });
  }
};
```

In it, I define the url for my remote source, how to handle the query, and how to return the data for consumption by the typeahead.

Once I define my bloodhound instance, I then initialize it:

`taSource.initialize(true);`

I then define my typeahead object to use the bloodhound instance:

```
$('#search-input').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 3
}, {
  name: 'myMatches',
  source: taSource,
  display: 'Value'
});
```

Here is [a link to a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/vrcg4ofg/) demonstrating the basic use of remote sources.